# Does Multicollinearity between categorical variables affect the predictions in logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, multicollinearity

How do we check for multicollinearity between categorical variables?  Does multicollinearity between categorical variables make the logistic regression model unstable?

Answer (score 3):

Per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity):

> Multicollinearity does not reduce the predictive power or reliability of the model as a whole, at least within the sample data set

**Prediction will not be affected**, even for a logistic regression model.

Multicollinearity will make the model coefficients unstable - the standard errors will be greater in the presence of multicollinearity. See [here](https://www3.nd.edu/~rwilliam/stats2/l11.pdf).

You can still use the [VIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor) to assess multicollinearity among categorical variables. the `vif` function in the `car` package in r will do this (although, I'm not sure *how* it works with categorical variables).

Condition Indices can also be used to assess multicollinearity. See [here](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/insight/chap39/sect29.htm) and [here](http://faculty.cas.usf.edu/mbrannick/regression/Collinearity.html).

Comment: Coefficient estimates i logistic regression are not unbiased